# Is 'peek().min; ' returning the lowest value in this code?

Tags: java

I have the following class, superclass and main codes below. I am unsure as to what 'peek().min' is doing. I get that if its the first number that is being passed in, Integer.MAX_VALUE is returned, thereby making the Math.min() output select the value that it was passed in as. However, I don't get what peek().min does since the return is a value from a stack node (top.data). Top being the node and data being the value. What then does '.min' do?

superclass:

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class Stack<NodeWithMin>{

    private static class StackNode<T>{
        private T data;
        private StackNode<T> next;

        public StackNode(T data){
            this.data = data;
        }
    }



    private StackNode<NodeWithMin> top;

    public NodeWithMin pop() throws EmptyStackException {
        if(top == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
        NodeWithMin item = top.data;
        top = top.next;
        return item;
    }

    public void push(NodeWithMin item){
        StackNode<NodeWithMin> t = new StackNode<NodeWithMin>(item);
        t.next = top;
        top = t;
    }

    public NodeWithMin peek() throws EmptyStackException {
        if(top==null) throw new EmptyStackException();
        return top.data;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return top == null;
    }

}
```

class:

```
public class StackWithMin extends Stack<NodeWithMin>{

    public void push(int value){
        int newMin = Math.min(value, min());
        super.push(new NodeWithMin(value, newMin));
    }

    public int min(){
        if(this.isEmpty()){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        else{
            return peek().min;
        }
    }

}

class NodeWithMin{
    public int value;
    public int min;
    public NodeWithMin(int v, int min){
        value = v;
        this.min = min;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StackWithMin obj = new StackWithMin();

        obj.push(8);
        obj.push(3);
        obj.push(5);

        System.out.println(obj.min());

    }
}
```

Comment: peek it looking at the last added node, so when you are doing a push it is comparing the min of the last added value vs the value that you are adding now.

Comment: What does '.min' do?

Comment: I don't think there is comparison in that push you are talking about. You mean in the 'newMin'?

Comment: I'm just going to guess that a stack with nodes is returned and '.min' gives you the minimum value in that stack. How it does it? I am not sure

Comment: `public int min;` - it returns this value

Comment: Yeah. How is peek().min tied to the separate class NodeWithMin? I guess the node that gets returned by peek(), because its of type NodeWithMin can give you its public int min value.

Comment: Nevermind, i see it. The node is storing two values at the same time. I had thought it was doing one value.